# Getting Null Pointer exception while saving ModelAttribute [Spring MVC]

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, modelattribute

Working on a Spring MVC based project, I am getting the following code while I try to save review (Bean). I am able to get the data into controller successfully but for some reason getting a NULL pointer exception while saving.

Here is the code

-- JSP--

```
      <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="p-b">
                                <cf:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/reviews/add" id="reviewAction" modelAttribute="review" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                                    <div style="display:none">
                                        <cf:input path="tutorId" type="hidden" name="tutorId" id="tutorId" value="" />
                                        <cf:input path="studentId" type="hidden" name="studentId" id="studentId" value="${sessionScope.user.userId}" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label>Your Comment / Review</label>
                                    <cf:textarea path="reviewMessage" name="reviewMessage" required="required"/>
                                    <p class="text-right"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" name="submit" value="Post"> </p>
                                </cf:form>
                            </div>
                        </div>



     <cf:hidden path="userId" id="userId"/>



     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("Calling getTutorId()");

        getTutorId();

    });

    function getTutorId()
    {
        $('#tutorId').attr('value',$('#userId').val());

    }
    </script>
```

-- Controller --

```
      @RequestMapping (value = "/add" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public String addReview(@Valid @ModelAttribute Review review , BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    try {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(bindingResult.getAllErrors().iterator().next().toString());
            return "FindTutor";
        }

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String newDate = dateFormat.format(date); //06/08/2016 15:59:48

        review.setDate(newDate);
        review.setReviewStatus("Disapproved");

        //Just for testing purposes
        System.out.println(review.getStudentId());
        System.out.println(review.getTutorId());
        System.out.println(review.getDate());
        System.out.println(review.getReviewMessage());
        System.out.println(review.getReviewStatus());
        //Just for testing purposes

            reviewBL.saveReview(review);

        List<Subject> subjectList = subjectBL.getAllSubjects();
        List<User> userList = manageUserBL.getAllUsers();

        model.addAttribute("subjectList", subjectList);
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "FindTutor";
}
```

-- Business Logic Class --

```
    @Service
  public class ReviewBL {

private ReviewsMongoRepository reviewsMongoRepository;

public void saveReview(Review review)
{
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(review.getId())) {
        review.setId(null);
    }

    reviewsMongoRepository.save(review);
}


}
```

-- Bean Class --

```
  @Document (collection = "reviews")
  public class Review {

@Id
private String Id;

private String tutorId;

private String studentId;

private String date;

private String reviewMessage;

private String reviewStatus;

// plus constructors also all of the getters and setters

}
```

I am getting the following error message, and as you can see the data (Model Attribute is successfully been captured in the controller but is not being saved in the database due to a NULL pointer exception error that I can't seem to find out why

```
       2016-05-28 13:16:59 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO           e.b.fyp.stp.web.filter.SessionFilter - Filtering: /reviews/add
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at edu.bnu.fyp.stp.bl.ReviewBL.saveReview(ReviewBL.java:23)
at  edu.bnu.fyp.stp.web.controller.student.ReviewController.addReview(ReviewControll er.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at edu.bnu.fyp.stp.web.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

  574939f19fcf9da523b63f8b // ID 1 (String)
  57493a3e9fcf9da523b63f8c // ID 2 (String)
  28/05/2016 13:16:59 //Date (String)
  Great Tutor // Message (String)
  Disapproved //Status (String)

  2016-05-28 13:16:59 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] INFO       e.b.fyp.stp.web.filter.SessionFilter - Filtering: /WEB-INF/jsp/FindTutor.jsp
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. It was because I didn't apply @Autowired on reviewsMongoRepository so it wasn't linked with the review bean. I corrected this and now it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Inside **ReviewBL.saveReview** you are calling **reviewsMongoRepository.save(review)** 
But I can see you havent initialized **reviewsMongoRepository**, this is just a reference type reffering to "nothhing." It might be the cause of your Null Pointer exception